# How to remove the label after bisecting

Tags: git, git-bisect

I tried to run a bisect to locate an issue and when it's done I called `git bisect reset`:

```
$ git bisect reset
We are not bisecting.
```

But then the label of `good` is still there, how can I remove this label?
It shows something like this in `git log`:

```
commit c561e7297... (good)
```

Comment: You might be using `git bisect` incorrectly.  Please show the exact commands you used before you tried to run `git bisect reset`.

Comment: I run `git bisect start` then `git bisect good` then several `good and bad` commands, then finally run `reset`.

Comment: Oops, never mind previous (deleted) comment, you're using reset correctly. Anyway, there's no issue with leaving the `good` label around—it's just a label.

Comment: @torek it gives wrong impression that this commit is good, so i wanna get rid of it :)

Comment: Normally `git bisect reset` should clean out `refs/bisect/` which should get rid of it. You could run `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/bisect | xargs git update-ref -d` to delete them all, or just `git update-ref -d refs/bisect/good` to delete the `good` one.

Comment: Hmm, this is weird, because this is no `refs/bisect/good` in `.git`, `refs/bisect` is empty.

Comment: Hmm, i just found there is `refs/heads/good`...

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I run git bisect start then git bisect good

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git), here is the procedure you should follow when using `git bisect`:

```
$ git bisect start
$ git bisect bad        # mark current commit as bad
$ git bisect good v1.0  # mark some earlier commit as good
```

Git bisect basically just does a binary search to find the first bad commit where some problem popped up in your branch.  It expects you to mark a certain commit as good, then some earlier commit as bad.  Because you marked the current commit as good first, without specifying a bad commit, my guess is that bisect just completed without doing anything.

Comment: I don't think that `(good)` is actually a permanent part of the history.  It should go away on its own AFAIK, after running `git bisect reset`.

Comment: But I have run `git bisect reset` several times, it is still there, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: Try running these 4 commands: `git bisect start`, `git bisect bad`, `git bisect good HEAD`, `git bisect reset`.  This is a no-op complete bisect, which hopefully will reset things.

Comment: If your stage and WD are empty, try doing a `git reset --hard`.  Anyway, the label is not really there, and should have no effect on your Git.